# How to read latitude and longitude from LatLng

Tags: angular, leaflet

I would like to read separately latitude and longitude values from LatLng object.

In order to do so, I nave created the following:

```
var latLng = L.marker(data[0]).getLatLng(); 
console.log(latLng); // this outputs LatLng {lat: 45.285639154610315, lng: 20.27291721572189}
var lat = latLng.lat; // this breaks
var lng = latLng.lng;
console.log(lat);
```

Does anyone know how to get latitude and longitude values correctly?

Comment: Breaks how? Is there an error message?

Comment: This code produce no error message.